# react-final-form remove initial values on form.reset

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-final-form

I have a react-final-form which can pre-populate using `initialValues` like so:

```
<Form
  onSubmit={onSubmit}
  initialValues={filterParams}
  render={({ handleSubmit, values, form }) => (
  <form id="productsFilterForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  ...
```

This works great, prefilling the form as I want. But I also have a reset button that triggers `form.reset()`. When a user clicks this, I want it to completely reset the form, ignoring the `initialValues` but everything I have tried always maintains these. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass new `initialValues` to [`form.reset()`](https://final-form.org/docs/final-form/types/FormApi#reset). You want `form.reset({})`.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.. That's perfect thank you!